# Getting non-existing ids of textarea on each function of javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created user form dynamically in which all input and textarea controls are getting created dynamically. Here in below code, i am trying to fetch the ids of all input and textarea of particular form and in case of input, getting right values but getting wrong values for textarea.

```
$('#Detailcontact input, textarea').each(function() {   
    arr[i++] = this.id;
});
```

Only one textarea is on form, but this function returns multiple non-existing ids of textarea.

Comment: can  u create a link pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do:

```
$('#Detailcontact input, #Detailcontact textarea').each(function() {  
  arr[i++] = this.id;
});
```

Or use `.find` instead.

```
$('#Detailcontact').find('input,textarea').each(function() {  
   arr[i++] = this.id;
});
```

You could also do with:

```
$('input,textarea', '#Detailcontact').each(function() {  
   arr[i++] = this.id;
});
```